# Do $\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R},x<k\}$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x<k\}$ mean the same thing?

Tags: notation

Short question about set-builder notation.

> Do 
>   $$D=\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{R}, x < k\}$$
>   and 
>   $$D=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < k\}$$ 
>   mean the same thing?

I see both of them used in different contexts and was wondering if they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same thing. I prefer $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < k \}$, because it is a clear separation between the domain ($\mathbb{R}$) and the condition ($x < k$). So I think it is easier to read, definitely when the condition gets more complicated.

Comment: So would your preferred notation read "x is an element of the reals, such that x is less than k"? In this case, the other notation sounds strange: "x, such that x is an element of the reals and x is less than k".

Comment: @SeanXie Yes, and exactly for the reason you mentioned it is my preferred notation.

Comment: I think they both have their uses; the first notation generalizes more easily to the notation $\{f(x) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Your example is still different though: $f(x)$ can be in a different domain than $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $f$ could be complex valued).